# Custom ActionMode for TextView doesn't work on all devices

Tags: android

I implemented a TextView with a custom ActionMode.Callback, where I add an item to the menu if certain criteria is met. This works like a charm on most devices (N4, N7, GS4) but now I noticed that it doesn't work on The LG G2. I don't have other devices to test it on, but LG has implemented the default TextView- ActionMode in a way that the menu is not shown in the actionbar, but on top of the selected text (much like it happens on iOS afaik) and I'm wondering whether somebody else had this experience and how I could solve it?

(Maybe it would also help to let me know of other apps that use a custom TextView action mode, so I can check, whether they work properly on this device, I couldn't think of one yet...)

Thanks,
j

Answer (score 1):

I found several other posts about the same behavior on HTC (sense) devices, and there was not a solution which somehow forces those stupid custom android versions to behave the way it's supposed to...

So I ended up adding the functionality in another way :(