# How To Disable Copy and Paste from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using following code but it is not working when cursor blink and I click on that paste button display.

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
    }

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I don't want to hide Cursor.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable copy/paste from/to EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275299/how-to-disable-copy-paste-from-to-edittext)

Comment: Do you have a paste button in your XML or is it the menu which opens in EditText itself?

Comment: @Sufian it opens EditText itself

Comment: Which Android API level are you running this on?

Comment: @Sufian  25 Nougat 7.1

Comment: Have you tried clean build?

Comment: @Sufian yes....

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Android versions provided by your device's manufacturer. See the question [Custom ActionMode for TextView doesn't work on all devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531237/custom-actionmode-for-textview-doesnt-work-on-all-devices). I wish they had put their solution in the answer. You could ask them though.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
edittext.setLongClickable(false);
edittext.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use longClickable in xml file like:

```
 <EditText
    ... your edittext
   android:longClickable = "false"/>
```

or you can try in java like

```
youredittext.setLongClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this just make your `editext`  `LongClickable` false like below code

**from XML**

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

**from JAVA**

```
edittext.setLongClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late but maybe I can help someone else. Everyone talk about  this setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback but has another callback setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback that you have to set.

This one receive exactly the same callback parameter so you can create this interface as a val and pass for both methods/fun.
Check code synthax before copy an paste, because I'm using Kotlin since 2019 o.o

```
private ActionMode.Callback callback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
}

public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    return false;
}

public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    return false;
}
});
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(callback) 
edittext.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(callback)
```